# Output Matrix field within Channel

Tags: craft3, templating

Very new to craft and hence sorry if this is very basic. I have created a service channel which contains some matrix fields. One for a list and one for button. My approach here may be wrong and hence please say if that is case. I appear to be in my service loop as the title and excerpt are outing, However, the matrix fields are not?

If I `{% dd serviceEntry %}` this shows `[serviceList] => null` which perhaps explains why the isn't outputting, but not why the fields are `null`?

```
  <div class="service card">
    {% for serviceEntry in craft.entries.section('service').limit(3).all() %}
      <h1>{{ serviceEntry.title }}</h1>
      <p>{{ serviceEntry.excerpt }}</p>
      {% for block in entry.serviceList %}
      <ul>
      {% switch block.type %}
        {% case 'list' %}
        {% set item = block.item.one() %}
          <li>{{ block.item }}</li>
      {% endswitch %}
      </ul>
      {% endfor %}
      <ul>
      {% for block in entry.serviceList %}
        {% if block.type == "list" %}
        <li>{{ block.item }}</li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Above are both the methods I have tried, neither of which work.

Handle: ServiceList
Field Type: Matrix
Block types: List
Fields: Item

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to help from Ryan on the Discord group, I found an answer. This being…

```twig
// Call the channel
{% for serviceEntry in craft.entries.section('service').limit(3).all() %}
  <h1>{{ serviceEntry.title }}</h1>
  <p>{{ serviceEntry.excerpt }}</p>
  <ul>
    // Call the block within the loop
    {% for block in serviceEntry.serviceList %}
      {% if block.type == "list" %}
        <li>{{ block.item }}</li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  // Same as above
  {% for block in serviceEntry.internalButton %}
    {% if block.type == "internalButton" %}
      // Create varible for url
      {% set url = block.buttonDestination.first() %}
      <a href="{{ url.getUrl }}" title="{{ block.buttonDescription }}" aria-label="Button Link">{{ block.buttonText }}</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```